# How to get residentadvisor API functional

Tags: xml, access-token

I´m trying to connect to the API of residentadvisor (http://www.residentadvisor.net/api/dj.asmx?op=getartist).

My goal is, to get all informations of DJs (tracks and labels) and labels (DJs and tracks) and the TOP100, TOP1000 and so on.
Unfortunatelly, there is no good manual for this API. I wrote to residentadvisor and got no answer.
There are some examples given, but I don´t know what are the example values:

```
<UserID>string</UserID>: Is this my login name?
<AccessKey>string</AccessKey> Is this my personal user password?
<DJID>string</DJID> Where can I find the DJID of a DJ?
<ArtistName>string</ArtistName> Ok, this is just the artist name, right?
<ChartID>string</ChartID>: Where can I find the ChartID?
<Option>string</Option>: What are the options?
<URL>string</URL> Which URL ist this?
```

Any hints?

Comment: No, the accessKey is not your password, it's your API access key. The question is, how to get one?

Answer (score 4):

I just contacted them and they replied within 24 hours: "There are no plans to release our API currently"

(Update: There is now an official app called RA Guide in Google Play and App Store https://ra.co/ra-guide)

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if it's still relevant for you but for others that are interested, the Resident Advisor API allows for GraphQL queries. You don't even need to supply an authorization token just make sure that you are specifying the `user-agent` header to something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`

Here is an example of a request in CURL format that i tried:

```
curl --location 'https://ra.co/graphql' \
--header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"query":"query GET_POPULAR_EVENTS($filters: FilterInputDtoInput, $pageSize: Int) {\r\n  eventListings(filters: $filters, pageSize: $pageSize, page: 1, sort: { attending: { priority: 1, order: DESCENDING } }) {\r\n    data {\r\n      id\r\n      listingDate\r\n      event {\r\n        ...eventFields\r\n        __typename\r\n      }\r\n      __typename\r\n    }\r\n    __typename\r\n  }\r\n}\r\n\r\nfragment eventFields on Event {\r\n  id\r\n  title\r\n  attending\r\n  date\r\n  contentUrl\r\n  flyerFront\r\n  queueItEnabled\r\n  newEventForm\r\n  images {\r\n    id\r\n    filename\r\n    alt\r\n    type\r\n    crop\r\n    __typename\r\n  }\r\n  venue {\r\n    id\r\n    name\r\n    contentUrl\r\n    live\r\n    __typename\r\n  }\r\n  __typename\r\n}","variables":{"filters":{"areas":{"eq":229},"listingDate":{"gte":"2023-06-01","lte":"2023-08-04"},"listingPosition":{"eq":1}},"pageSize":10}}'
```

Comment: Where did you get this info? is there an official documentation?

Comment: @RoccoDen91 No, I don't think there is an official documentation. I just checked out the browsers network requests.